# Login to a Django site using a POST request

Tags: django, vb.net, authentication

I'm writing a VB.NET program that needs to send data to a Django site, but the site is password protected. Therefore I need to log in first. The code I'm using right now is:

```
Dim reqT As HttpWebRequest
Dim resT As HttpWebResponse
reqT = WebRequest.Create("http://websiteURL/login/")
reqT.Method = "POST"

Dim Data As String
Data = "{""username"":""fakeusername""&""password"":""fakepassword""}"
Dim credArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data)
reqT.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
reqT.ContentLength = credArray.Length
Dim dataStreamT As Stream = reqT.GetRequestStream()
dataStreamT.Write(credArray, 0, credArray.Length)
dataStreamT.Close()
```

This is returning a 403 error from the webserver, unfortunately I'm not sure how to fix it. I think it might be the csrf failing or I might be formatting my POST data wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would guess that you are right about the csrf, but your data looks funny too.  I would think there should be a comma between the username and password.  The easy thing to do would be to use a tool such as tamper on Firefox and see exactly what is getting posted when a real user logs in.  But, I still think you are going to get rejected without a CSRF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like CSRF protection to me. The Django CSRF documentation is here:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

As per [the How It Works section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-it-works), your POST request will need to pass along the CSRF token, and the CSRF cookie.

If you make a GET request to the login page, you should be able to grab the token from the HTML source. I’m guessing you’d also have access to the cookie?

Comment: If it were this simple, then there would be no point to CSRF.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: doh, I knew I was missing something obvious. Re-written accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Paul. I set up my site to pull the source of the login page, and stripping out the value is easy enough, so I get something like "name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='<a big string of alphanumeric characters>'" Can I just append that on to my Data variable?

Comment: I think you need to read the CSRF cookie that comes back with the login page too, and pass that along with your POST request, as well as appending the token to your data variable. I’m not familiar with VB.NET, so I don’t soecifically know how you’d add a cookie to a request.